# Azure DataFactory Lookup startup time very long

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have a very simple Lookup in Azure Data Factory (self hosted runtime) which loads configuration data for subsequent steps.

[image: Pipeline Definition]

The "Read Import-Definition" which executes a stored procedure takes ~15-19s to complete while the actual SQL statement executed from SSMS executes in **less than a second**.

[image: Log]

The integration runtime is idling @0% CPU.

Even if we add another Lookup step directly afterwards the first step there seems to be still a "spinup"-overhead of 15s for each added step.

Is there anything we can do or is this expected behaviour?

Comment: If you click on the icons next to the slow activity name what’s the actual queue time? Regardless of whether CPU is 0% are there any other running activities on that SHIR? The monitoring tab will show you that.

Comment: Where is the SHIR in relation to your laptop and in relation to the database? Wondering if it’s in another data center and the connect time is a bit slow.

Comment: @GregGalloway The queue time is 3s, there are no other running activities on the IR. The SHIR is OnPemise, the database we read data from is an AzureSQL DB. The connection between the OnPremise server <-> Azure <-> Azure DB seems fine ... it's only the long wait time